# SQLite - Database file stops growing

Tags: c++, database, sqlite

I'm using [SRombauts SQLite Wrapper](https://github.com/SRombauts/SQLiteCpp) for C++ together with `SQLite` version `3.8.10.2` on a `Debian Jessie` machine.
I can `INSERT` or `SELECT` data without problems, but the strange thing is, that the database always stops growing at `56852480 bytes` (I've got this information from the `ls -l database.db` command).

What I'm trying to accomplish is to insert the data of a big (around `280'000` lines) csv file into the database.

Well, this is a simplified version of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <csv.h> //small csv class of mine
#include <SQLiteCpp/SQLiteCpp.h>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    SQLite::Database db("database.db", SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE);
    db.exec("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bernd");

    //simplified version of the table, there would be more columns
    db.exec("CREATE TABLE bernd(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, loads_of_data TEXT)");
    SQLite::Transaction tr;
    SQLite::Statement stmt("INSERT INTO bernd(loads_of_data) values(?)");

    Csv csv("file.csv");
    while(csv.getNext())
    {
        stmt.bind(1, csv.getValue("loads_of_data"));
        stmt.executeStep();
        stmt.reset();
    }
    tr.commit();
}
```

I know I should use some `try{} catch{}` blocks, but I wanted to keep the code small.

I read some things about `SQLite` limits but setting the only one slightly significant for this case, `SQLITE_MAX_PAGE_COUNT`, to it's maximum value made no difference.

What's going on here? It seems no one else encountered this problem and I'm really confused!
Any insight or hint into the right direction is highly appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked if what has been entered is even correct? Are you sure it's not just your program stopping its `INSERT`s because of some error in the `Csv` class? What happens if you try to manually `INSERT` something with the SQLite command-line client afterwards?

Comment: Oh, and perhaps it has something to do with the transaction. Have you tried removing it and see what happens then?

Comment: Is there actually a problem? Is some data missing?

Comment: The problem is not in the `Csv` class, i verified that it processes every single row. I also tried experimenting with the transaction, i.e. commiting it stepwise (every 1000, 5000 or 10000 steps), which changed nothing, if I remove it completely the task would need forever to complete, therefore I have not tried, will do if the problem is not solved until clock of.
Strangely I can indeed insert data afterwards and display it correctly.

Comment: So, it just completed without transaction and nothing changed.